# learning_curve returns nan values for train_sizes_abs

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I allways get nan values for train_sizes_abs from the sklearn learning_curve function:
(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html)

```
train_sizes_abs, train_score, val_score = learning_curve(model, X_train, y_train,
    cv=2,
    scoring="f1",
    shuffle=True,
    random_state=3,
    train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1, 5))
´´´

the model comes from a pipe, where I allready ran model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Your learning_curve function has more than 3 outputs. Could you try again by considering the other outputs as well when returning the outputs of the function and then print the one you are looking for?

Comment: If you are providing your own data and if dataset is big then try to reduce the size and give a try. i encounted once an issue with size.